# Search for all places in a city by name

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using Google Places API for fetching Doctors list in particular city.

But the problem here is that we can only have 20 results and with help of next_page_token in the response we can again fetch 20 more, by this we can only have 60 results.

So is there any other authentic way to fetch all the Doctors details?

And this is my query:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=doctor+in+Tehran&key=MY_API_KEY
```

**For information**: I don't want to use OpenStreetMap, MapQuest or other maps.

Comment: When you rank by distance, you can get the 20 closer. You can use optional parameters to add more criteria to your filters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any authentic way to get all the doctors from the Places API search. Places API is not working as a database search.

Additionally, there are certain restrictions in the Terms of Service that prevent such kind of functionality. Have a look at section 10.4.c(ii) of ToS:

> *No creation or augmentation of data sets based on Google’s Content or Services.* You will not use Google’s Content or Services to create or augment your own mapping-related dataset (or that of a third party), including a mapping or navigation dataset, **business listings database**, mailing list, or telemarketing list.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4